# SqlAlchemy performance: forbid querying e.g. in template generation?

Tags: performance, orm, sqlalchemy

I find a lot of performance issues with SqlAlchemy creep into my project when database lookup happens at e.g. the template generation stage.

Is it possible to tell SqlAlchemy that 'data gathering' has finished, and that any further queries to a session (e.g. as a side effect of accessing an instrumented attribute) are to raise an exception?

What other strategies have people used to ensure that an ORM performs well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in performance whether you make a database lookup during template generation or before that - the key is to avoid hammering the database with hundreds of queries regardless of where those queries originated.

What you need is to track the number of queries emitted during each request/response cycle - if you see many queries you know you need to optimize the way you access the data.

Many web frameworks contain "debug toolbar" functionality, for example Pyramid and Flask have one. If you use one of those frameworks it's just a matter of enabling it.

Otherwise, it's not difficult to roll your own:

```
class QueryStats(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.begin()

    def add_query(self, statement, parameters):
        self.queries += [(statement, parameters)]

    def begin(self):
        self.queries = []


def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context
    DBSession.stats.add_query(str(statement), str(parameters))


class SessionStatsBase(SessionBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        SessionBase.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.stats = QueryStats()

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(class_=SessionStatsBase, ...)
event.listen(engine, "before_cursor_execute", before_cursor_execute)
```

Then you just print a long list of queries at the bottom of the page, or, if you want, raise an exception if the request emitted more than, say, 100 queries.

Comment: Great answer, will try writing a version that raises an exception based on your code.